# Spring Boot ehcache in multi maven project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, ehcache

Im trying to use multiple ehcahe.xml configuration files in place of modules which will use defined caches.

When is the ehcache.xml configuration placed under resources of app-web module from where the spring boot application is started it works fine with `@EnableCaching`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ CommonApp.class, CoreConfig.class})
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableCaching
public class WebApplication extends WeblogicMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

But when is the configuration placed under the app-core module and `@EnableCaching` is moved under `CoreConfig` which is imported by `WebApplication` it fails on runtime.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableCaching
public class CoreConfig {

}
```

When `@Cacheable` method is called I'm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'systemParameterCache'
```

My idea is that every module can have own ehcache.xml configuration with the caches which belong to that module.

Is it possible to use like that? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. But I wouldn't recommend that. One cache manager in an application is enough. Having many is resource consuming for nothing. If you have trouble giving different names to your caches, I suggest that you use a module prefix.

Then, I'm not sure what you mean by modules. `@EnableCaching` is expected to be specified once in an application.

But if it's only specified on `CoreConfig` it should work. However, you still need to create `systemParameterCache` in your cache configuration. It seems to be your problem here.

Comment: My intention was to have just one CacheManager defined in `common` and share it through multiple modules (using `shared` for [EhCacheManagerFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.html#setShared-boolean-)) and than use this CacheManager instance in custom cache provider configured for appropriate module and cache using `ehcache.xml` configuration used from this module.

I was just curious if Spring Boot provides something like that by default.

Anyway thank you for your answer!